# Is Back Slash required for domain URL

Tags: web-services

Is a backslash required for accessing a domain URL?

Comment: your question is too vague. What do you mean by "accessing"? Also, backslashes (\) aren't used in URLs. Did you mean the forward slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

http://stackoverflow.com

Whether it's required for specific page URLs within a site depends on the server configuration.

(this is pretty easy to test on your own, by the way)

Comment: Theoretically there is no support for the empty path in HTTP, so only `http://stackoverflow.com/` would be a valid HTTP URL. But every sane browser assumes that that is what you meant anyway.

Comment: Yes. "Required by the specs" and "required to access" are often very different things. :-)

Comment: HI Guys,I am making an HttpConnection from my bb application,if i add the forward slash to domain,it works good,connection succesful,or else it shows 400 error,if i make the connection in Blackberry via wifi,if make this SIM.connection was successful.So only i asked abt this.